# Logging Redirect Location in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, log-files

Using the standard "Combined" log format, when Apache returns a 301 response it logs it in the access log, which is good, but it only logs the response code. It doesn't log the location to which the client is being directed. What argument do I need to add to the CustomLog format in order to get it to log this information? It wasn't obvious to me from the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the manual: `%{Location}o` ( http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats )

> %{Foobar}o    The contents of Foobar: header line(s) in the reply.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason every time I read that exact page that did not jump out at me.